# google.load only if specific page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api, google-ajax-api, google-ajax-libraries

i have this:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(googlata); //googlata() is a function to create a google cse
google.load('search', '1');
```

I want to run the top code only if the page opened is

```
www.example.com/example
```

i tried with this:

```
var paginaricerca= self.location.href;
var Searchpage= paginaricerca.indexOf('example')+7; 
var urlpage= paginaricerca.slice(0,Searchpage);
if(urlpage=='www.example.com/example'){
     google.setOnLoadCallback(googlata); 
     google.load('search', '1');    
}
```

but doesn't work....

is there an another way ?

thanks a lot !!! :)

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand. What framework are you using? Are you unable to simply put the `google.load` code on `/example`? Please provide more context

Comment: i have a big file added each page of my webiste, but i want to run a portion of this file only in one specific page. If the page opened is my specific page so the code in the first post must run. Sorry for my english but i'm italian :/

Answer (score 0):

location.href gives you the current url, not sure what you are trying to do with the slicing but you should be able to compare it to a string of the url you want to check

```
var paginaricerca = self.location.href;
var urlCheck = 'http://example.com/example';

if (paginaricerca === urlCheck) {
     google.setOnLoadCallback(googlata); 
     google.load('search', '1');    
}
```

Comment: maybe the problem is that i add this code in $(document).ready() ?